# Is it possible to move all printers to a new Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I just got my wife a new MacBook Pro and I'm about finished with transitioning from her old one to the new one.

One thing I have yet to do is setup the printers.

Is there a way to move all of the connected printers from her old MBP to the new one without having to set them all up from scratch again?

Comment: Is the old Mac running Snow Leopard as well? If not, then your mileage may vary.

Comment: No, it's not :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the problems [some people reported](http://www.macosxhints.com/search.php?query=10.6+printer&mode=search&type=all&keyType=all) with printers during (early adopter) updates from 10.5 to 10.6, I'd not try to migrate the drivers...

Just plug-in the printers and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks, After I did some more research I came to the same conclusion